# grab a substring from a string and print it

Tags: php, string, variables, substring, preg-match

this is my string:in variable $raw

> Movie Title: Ittefaq (2017) Director: Abhay Chopra Stars: Sonakshi
>   Sinha, Sidharth Malhotra, Akshaye Khanna Release Date: 3 November 2017
>   (India) Genres: Mystery, Thriller Format: MatRoska (Mkv) File Size:
>   850MB Resolution: 1280x536 Runtime: 01:45:31 Language: Hindi
>   Subtitles: English [Softcoded] - Muxed Encoder: MkvCage (MC) Team
>   Source: Hon3y /

and now i want to extract "850MB" from it.

Note: the whole string is changed every time.
but keywords like "File Size:", "resolution" remain same but their value changes.

i only want to extract value of file size from it.

Comment: Is this the exact raw string?  Are there line breaks in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get all possible values, you could use :

```
if (preg_match('~File Size: ([^\s]+)~', $raw, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Will get the string from `File Size:` until the next whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following pattern will be tight enough to only capture what you need and not by mistake get something else in the text.

```
/Size: ([\d\.MGTB]+)/
```

It will accept digits, dots and MB, GB, TB filesizes.
(If filesizes are with dots, ex. 1.35 GB)

```
preg_match("/Size: ([\d\.MGTB]+)/", $raw, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$raw = 'Movie Title: Ittefaq (2017) Director: Abhay Chopra Stars: Sonakshi Sinha, Sidharth Malhotra, Akshaye Khanna Release Date: 3 November 2017 (India) Genres: Mystery, Thriller Format: MatRoska (Mkv) File Size: 850MB Resolution: 1280x536 Runtime: 01:45:31 Language: Hindi Subtitles: English [Softcoded] - Muxed Encoder: MkvCage (MC) Team Source: Hon3y /';

$matches = [];
preg_match("/Size: ([\da-zA-Z]+)/", $raw, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

The example above will output:

```
850MB
```

Comment: This will not capture GB file sizes.

Comment: i want both can u plz edt ur answer

Comment: @Andreas, it will capture everything like numbers and letters.

Comment: Nope! Try it and you will see. Also there is no need for `a-z` it may only make it capture a incorrect part of the string

Comment: What about "8.5GB"?

Comment: So it's not about "GB", but generally about the format :)

Comment: Depends on how you see it. Generally in GB you get a decimal number. In MB it's gerenally rounded off.